# Ubuntu not accepting my arduino

Tags: programming, arduino

I am relatively new to Ubuntu, and have been enjoying it. However, it detects my Arduino Mega 2560 (it appears as `/dev/tty/ACM0`), but outputs these messages:

```
avrdude: stk500_send(): failed to send command to serial port
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer
```

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Did you set the udev rules for it?

Comment: @AndroidDev sorry, I don't know what that is

Comment: Did you run the `arduino-linux-setup.sh` file included in the Arduino IDE download?

Comment: @AndroidDev yeah I did

Comment: Did you reboot after running it like it prompted? Also which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: @AndroidDev I rebooted after installation. I am using 18.04 LTS. Should we move this to a chat?

Comment: That probably would be a good idea but do you have enough rep points for that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96733/discussion-between-myspace-and-android-dev).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone who is having this issue, here is a temporary fix.

Thanks to @AndroidDev, here is an easy fix that works well enough.

1. Find out which port your Arduino is using (look in the bottom right corner or in the menu)
2. Go to terminal and do `sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyfoo` (fill in the last part with your part)
3. Open Arduino and carry on!

The issue with this solution is that you must redo steps 2&3 every time you use Arduino, so try to write a script or something which does it automatically and post it here so others can use it.

Comment: That's not recommended. You're giving read and write access to everyone! You should probably add the particular user that's trying to use the port to the group that has access to it (usually `dialout`).

Comment: Ok... then change it. Most people (like myself) shouldn't care since if you really didn't want someone else to throw code onto your Arduino, just unplug it. Also, another user most likely wouldn't be on at the same time as you... You're saying I should be worrying about a use case which wouldn't occur for most people and that it isn't recommended. I don't really see a purpose of leaving a comment on a seven month old thread...